# Get Item Count for a Specific View

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

Is there a piece of jQuery or JavaScript that I can run that will allow me to create a Content Editor Web Part that has "This is the number of list items: XYZed."

I've tried this but it is not working:

http://www.martinhatch.com/2010/09/how-to-achieve-count-on-large.html

The one I tried was the 4'th attempt. If someone could help me that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

try these solutions/posts in the given order.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5477/getting-a-count-of-list-items-in-a-list-via-ecmascript
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18050/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-items-in-a-list
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/266281/jQUERY-TO-GET-COUNT-OF-TOTAL-ITEMS-EXISTED-IN-SP-L

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. All I had to do was create the grouped view and put the url into the code. Tho I used quotes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

//////////
// you will need to change this URL
var url = "http://sppos/Lists/Statistics/Grouped.aspx";
////////// 

var groupings = [];

$.get(url, function(data) {
$(data).find("tbody[id^=titl][groupString] > tr > td").each(

function(index, value){
groupings.push($(this).text());
}
);

$("#placeholder").append("<ul></ul>");

$.each(groupings, function(index, value){

$("#placeholder ul").append("<li>" + value + "</li>")
});
});
});

</script>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

After testing, no quotes doesn't work, which may be the cause of some grief